# Forward tethered device?

Tags: cyanogenmod, networking, mobile-network, iptables

Alright, so I have a raspberry pi (192.168.42.53 on rndis0) that is tethered to an android tablet to access the internet. The tablet is connected to my home LAN via WiFi (on wlan0). How do I forward the raspberry pi so that I can access all of it's services through devices on my home LAN? Could this work through iptables?

Comment: If SSH is on the default port, then allow port 22 incoming? Just a guess...

Comment: Have you tried using the terminal to change your iptables or what it's called?

Comment: @ionree yes, but I am not sure how to use iptables exactly

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question that is a really easy fix.  Turns out, iptables is not at all needed.  There is an easy to use app on the play store that solved my problem: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.bherbst.net&hl=en